# Windows Server 2k8 - Adding User To Admin Group But Not True Admin?

Tags: windows-server-2008, groups

It appears that adding a user to the Administrators group does not actually grant the user full Administrative privileges on the server. I am still not able to add users to the system (Access Denied) with this particular account. What is going on?

Comment: Post the output of the `whoami /all` command run from an elevated command prompt while logged-on as the user in question, please.

Comment: OKay, I guess I was mistaken. Using the elevated command prompt I am able to create a user but with the standard prompt I am not. I suppose a better question is what is the difference between and Administrator command prompt and its "elevated" counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

UAC (User Account Control) runs users in a standard session, even if they are an administrator. Administrators have the ability to launch programs with elevated privilege, which is why your administrative command prompt can do what you want, but a standard one cannot.